# Flutter Slide Transition To a Specific Location

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, transition, slide

I'm making a grammar quiz app using flutter, I have a question and a couple of choices, I want to make the choice slides to the empty space part of the question with a slide animation

For example:

## How is _ new School?

## (You) (Your) (It)

and when I press on (Your) the choice widget slides to the _ leaving an empty container

## How is (Your) new School?

## (You) ( ) (It)

I Made it with Draggable and DragTarget and you can see it in these images

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCO3F.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPRil.png)

but I want it to slide when I press on it without dragging and dropping

here is some of the code

```
class QuestionsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  QuestionsScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuestionsScreenState createState() => _QuestionsScreenState();
}

class _QuestionsScreenState extends State<QuestionsScreen> {
  String userAnswer = "_";
  int indexOfDragPlace = QuestionBrain.getQuesitonText().indexOf("_");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Center(
                child: Scrollbar(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: [

                            ...QuestionBrain.getQuesitonText()
                                .substring(0, indexOfDragPlace)
                                .split(" ")
                                .map((e) => QuestionHolder(
                                      question: e + " ",
                                    )),

                            _buildDragTarget(),

                            ...QuestionBrain.getQuesitonText()
                                .substring(indexOfDragPlace + 1)
                                .split(" ")
                                .map((e) => QuestionHolder(
                                      question: e + " ",
                                    )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
     
            Wrap(
              children: [
                ...QuestionBrain.choices.map((choice) {
                  if (choice == userAnswer) {
                    return ChoiceHolder(
                      choice: "",
                      backGroundColor: Colors.black12,
                    );
                  }
                  return DraggableChoiceBox(
                    choice: choice,
                    userAnswer: userAnswer,
                    onDragStarted: () {
                      setState(() {
                        dragedAnswerResult = "";
                      });
                    },
                    onDragCompleted: () {
                      setState(() {
                        userAnswer = choice;
                        setState(() {
                          answerColor = Colors.orange;
                        });
                        print("Called");
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }).toList()
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildDragTarget() {
    return DragTarget<String>(
      builder: (context, icoming, rejected) {
        return Material(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.20,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
            color: answerColor,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Text(
                userAnswer,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
   
      onAccept: (data) {
        userAnswer = data;
        answerColor = Colors.orange;
      },
   
    );
  }

 
}


class DraggableChoiceBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const DraggableChoiceBox({
    Key key,
    this.choice,
    this.userAnswer,
    this.onDragCompleted,
    this.onDragStarted,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String choice;
  final String userAnswer;
  final Function onDragCompleted;
  final Function onDragStarted;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable(
      onDragCompleted: onDragCompleted,
      data: choice,
      child: ChoiceHolder(choice: choice),
      feedback: Material(
        elevation: 20,
        child: ChoiceHolder(
          choice: choice,
          margin: 0,
        ),
      ),
      childWhenDragging: ChoiceHolder(
        choice: "",
        backGroundColor: Colors.black12,
      ),
      onDragStarted: onDragStarted,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share some of your code that you already tried.

Comment: @HasilT I added some of the code, do you need more clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overlays` similar  to the way `Hero` widgets work, here is an "unpolished" example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SlideToPosition extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SlideToPositionState createState() => _SlideToPositionState();
}

class _SlideToPositionState extends State<SlideToPosition> {
  GlobalKey target = GlobalKey();

  GlobalKey toMove = GlobalKey();
  double dx = 0.0, dy = 0.0, dxStart = 0.0, dyStart = 0.0;
  String choosedAnswer = '', answer = 'answer', finalAnswer = '';

  OverlayEntry overlayEntry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => TweenAnimationBuilder(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        tween:
            Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(dxStart, dyStart), end: Offset(dx, dy)),
        builder: (context, offset, widget) {
          return Positioned(
            child: Material(
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    height: 29,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Center(child: Text(choosedAnswer)))),
            left: offset.dx,
            top: offset.dy,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text('text'),
                Container(
                  key: target,
                  height: 30,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Center(child: Text(finalAnswer)),
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide())),
                ),
                Text('text')
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue[200],
                  child: Center(child: Text(answer, key: toMove))),
              onTap: () async {
                setState(() {
                  answer = '';
                });
                RenderBox box1 = target.currentContext.findRenderObject();

                Offset targetPosition = box1.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

                RenderBox box2 = toMove.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                Offset toMovePosition = box2.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
                
                setState(() {
                  answer = '';
                  choosedAnswer = 'answer';
                });
                dxStart = toMovePosition.dx;
                dyStart = toMovePosition.dy;
                dx = targetPosition.dx;
                dy = targetPosition.dy;

                Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
                setState(() {});

                await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

                overlayEntry.remove();
                setState(() {
                  finalAnswer = 'answer';
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry for the poor naming of the variables :)

Comment: Thank you mate, you helped a lot